# Notification builder not supported below 4.1. How do I specify to only use notification builder with 4.1 and up and disregard below 4.1

Tags: android, android-activity, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-version

I am thinking if statement for isJellyBeanOrHigher() but don't know how to implement it.  Any suggestions on how to solve my issue would be very helpful.  Below 4.1 it crashes the program.

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(
                    mContext.getString(R.string.ui_maps_display_notification_title))
            .setContentText(
                    getResources().getString(
                            R.string.ui_maps_display_notification_content))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pi)
            .build();
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification.flags = notification.flags
            | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

edit:

```
 Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(
                    mContext.getString(R.string.ui_maps_display_notification_title))
            .setContentText(
                    getResources().getString(
                            R.string.ui_maps_display_notification_content))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentIntent(pi)
            .build();
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification.flags = notification.flags
            | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the compatibility library? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

Comment: Agreed. `NotificationCompat.Builder` works back to API Level 4 and is *strongly* encouraged.

Comment: I just changed  Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this) to Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder.(this)  I am assuming that this is the correct path.  I need to set up the emulator this afternoon.  I am at work sneaking in some code and can do it now.

Comment: I have it working on my phone 4.4. Changing it to NotificationCompat.Builder will solve the issue if I ran the app on a phone that is 4.0.3?

Comment: I am dying to test it but cant at this time.

Comment: @Guardanis if that works when I get home, write your answer below so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what version of the OS your app is running on:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

You'll also have to annotate your function with `@TargetApi()` to prevent compiler warnings when calling a method within the checked block.

I also agree with Guardanis, you should try out `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Answer (score 0):

Check against [`android.os.Build.VERSION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html).

> - `CODENAME`: The current development codename, or the string "REL" if this is a release build.
> - `INCREMENTAL`:  The internal value used by the underlying source control to represent this build.
> - `RELEASE`:  The user-visible version string.

Comment: None of those have anything to do with what API level the device is running on. That is `SDK_INT`.